# Adding watermark to video/picture after capture using react-native-camera

Tags: react-native, image-processing, video-processing, react-native-camera

Hye, is there any processing library or any ways to include watermark to video and picture for both platform (ios and android) using react-native ?

Answer (score 3):

[react-native-image-marker](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-image-marker) is an excellent library for adding water-mark to photos. It supports both text and image water marking.

Demo:

[image]

Comment: does this one support for video type also ?

Comment: Video not supported in this library. For that take a look at https://github.com/shahen94/react-native-video-processing

Comment: that package not supported for watermark for video.. thanks btw, I guess probably need to process the watermark for video on server.

Comment: It's a good idea to offload memory intensive tasks to back-end.